# reactjs sidebar with react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and have been trying to find an example of how to create a side nav bar in reactjs and use reactrouter with with it. Right now, I have a "side nav" pane that looks like this:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router';

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <nav>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</IndexLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/courses" activeClassName="active">Courses</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/about" activeClassName="active">About</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default Header;
```

but I want to turn that into a side nav bar but can't seem to find anything online with an example on how to do that.

-------EDIT--------

So I tried this, but still no luck...

app.js looks like this:

```
// This component handles the App template used on every page.
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import SideBar from './common/Header';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                        <SideBar />
                        {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default App;
```

SideBar component:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router';

const SideBar = () => {
    return (
        <nav>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <IndexLink to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</IndexLink>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/courses" activeClassName="active">Courses</Link>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/about" activeClassName="active">About</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default SideBar;
```

style.css looks like this:

```
#app {
    font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    min-width: 550px;
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

a.active {
    color: orange;
}

nav {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;

    > * { height: 100%; }

    .sidebar {
        width: 250px;
    }

    .content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can easily create a sidebar by creating a dom element with the following css: 

position: fixed; width:250px; top: 0; left:0; height: 100%; background: red;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more a CSS problem than a React problem - anything can be made a sidebar with the right CSS. That said, there's a good way to set this up in React as well, so I'll show you that.

I would suggest having the following, or something close.

The router would be structured in the following way:

```
<Route path="/" component={WrapperComponent}/>
    <Route path="/somepath" component={SomeComponent}/>
    ...
</Route>
```

`WrapperComponent` would look like

```
class WrapperComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <SideBar props... />
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Your `SideBar` class would look more or less like what you have above (but renamed, because it matters ;))

This would automatically place the current view inside `WrapperComponent` where `{ this.props.children }` is, beside the sidebar (assuming you have your styling correctly set up). In this example, navigating to `/something` would result in a split layout with your sidebar on the left and `SomeComponent` being rendered on the right.

For styles, something like

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.container > * { height: 100%; }

.container .sidebar {
    width: 250px;
}

.container .content {
    width: 100%;
}
```

would get you close.

*edit* there are a couple things wrong with the code you're using - even if you copy/paste my updated styles:

1. you're using `.container-fluid` instead of `.container`, which my styles use. If you're using Bootstrap, instead of `display: flex`, just use bootstrap columns (i.e. `col-md-3` on the sidebar and `col-md-9` on the content) - or avoid Bootstrap collisions by using something other than `.container(-fluid)` for the container name.
2. `SideBar` needs a `className` (`.sidebar`) if you want the styles to apply. `SideBar` is just the component class and does no effect on the HTML classnames. You can change `.sidebar` to `nav`, if that's easier for you.
3. either wrap `{ this.props.children }` in something with `.content` as a class or make sure whatever is being rendered there has that class. This could be accomplished by accepting a `className` prop to potential elements.
4. making something is fun - but you need to understand what you're doing as well. Just copy/pasting something from here into your codebase without first understanding what it means/what it's doing is wasting your time (imo).

Comment: Tried to do what you stated but I still can't seem to get it to work...I made an edit above too to show what I did...

Comment: The styles I posted are more or less `.scss`, not `.css`. I'll update them.

Comment: @user2061886 also, you need to re-class the elements you're using if you're going to copy/paste my code.